# Merging Arrays and putting them into a a dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays. One for date, one for month and one for year. I want to merge all the arrays so the values of the day, month and year arrays all have separate values in one array.

**Example:**

I want to turn:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 05
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 31
)
Array
(
    [0] => 04
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 12
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013
    [1] => 1998
    [2] => 2006
)
```

into

```
Array
(
    [0] => 05/04/2013
    [1] => 18/11/1998
    [2] => 31/12/2006
)
```

I have looked at merging arrays or appending arrays but this doesn't seem to work. The reason I want them in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` is so then I have a date format when I put these dates into my mysql database.

Comment: Take a look at `array_map()` and loop through all 3 arrays to combine them into 1 array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
$days = [5, 18, 31];
$months = [4, 11, 12];
$years = [2013, 1998, 2006];

$result = array_map(
    function ($d, $m, $y) {
        return sprintf("%s/%s/%s", $d, $m, $y);
        // return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', sprintf("%s/%s/%s", $d, $m, $y)); <-- if you need a DateTime object
    },
    $days,
    $months,
    $years
);
```

### Pay attention

`[]` is short array syntax introduced since php 5.4, if you're running on older version, use the canonical `array()`

Comment: Hi! is there a way I can do the dateTime thing but without the time?

Comment: @Ben from that object, you can simply retrieve date, but if you need only the string (because you don't need that specific format) you can choose the uncommented solution. However if you want to use DateTime object and retrive date directly from here, use `->format('d/m/Y')` onto each array element

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$days = array(05, 18, 31);
$months = array(04, 11, 12);
$years = array(2013, 1998, 2006);

$result = array_map(
    function ($d, $m, $y) {
        return sprintf("%d/%d/%d", $d, $m, $y);
    },
    $days,
    $months,
    $years
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: uhm, how your answer add something that I haven't already wrote in mine?

Comment: and ... so? If you can't provide an alternative answer, you should not write one.

Comment: used %d - Signed decimal number (negative, zero or positive) instead of %s

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$newArray = array();
$array1 = array(05,18,31);
$array2 = array(04,11,12);
$array3 = array(2013,1998,2006);

$i=0;
foreach($array1 as $value) {
    $newArray[] = $value.'/'.$array2[$i].'/'.$array3[$i];
    $i++;
}
  echo '<pre>';print_r($newArray);exit;
?>
```